# Getting width of div with a parent display: none in Jquery Tab Control

Tags: jquery, width

I have a jquery tab control in which I am building a custom control I've create which needs to know the width of itself during the build process.

My problem is when put into a parent container, in this case a tab, which has a 'display: none'  I am unable to calculate the width.

I've tried it both ways in my control:

```
$('.DataRow').width()
$('.DataRow').css('width')
```

both return 0.

Is there any other way to get at this width value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have often used this `visibility: hidden` technique. You can test width when `visibility:hidden`, but not `display:none`. Both hide the visibility of the element, however `display:none` behaves differently in that it does not take up any "space" in the DOM.

**Given this markup:**

```
<div id="parent" style="display: none">
    <div> find my width </div>
</div>
```

**Test the width:**

```
$('#parent').css('visibility', 'hidden').show();
var w = $('#parent div').width();
$('#parent').css('visibility', 'visible').hide();
console.log('width: ', w);
```

**Outputs:**

```
> width:  496
```

[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/8JBW5/)

## Update:

With jQuery UI Tabs you can do something like this:

```
$('#tabs-3').css('visibility', 'hidden').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');
```

Where `'#tabs-3'` is the hidden tab. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynPh2/) for more information.

Comment: This will work in that example, but doesn't seem to work when the parent div is within a jquery tab control.

Comment: @Collin Estes - most likely you have another parent container that is hidden, besides the one you modified.

Comment: @Collin Estes - here is a new jsfiddle using jquery ui tabs. You need to remove the class that does `display:none`. http://jsfiddle.net/ynPh2/

Comment: Yes this for sure works, I came to same solution just now and then came back and saw this.  In this control I can't assume they will always be sitting in tabs so I was hoping to be more generic but that 'ui-tabs-hide' class always takes precedence over everything else you try to do.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure theres' a better way, but as a quick fix:

```
$('.DataRow').show(); //show it
var w = $('.DataRow').width()  //get the width
$('.DataRow').hide(); //hide it
```

The code executes so quickly you'll never see it. (might wanna check it on slower/older browsers though) 
Like i said, this is a quick fix - i've had to do it myself and it works, but i'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: doesn't seem to work with the jquery tab control as the parent.  I think it probably is because the style of the tab control has a class with display: none marked '!important'

Comment: Well it is built in the Jquery tab UI so not sure I want to start changing that.