# Reading and setting selector / img width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `img` element defined by `id` in my HTML.  In JavaScript, I have a function that sets that element's image source.  Whatever I tried, I could not get the dimensions back using `$('#name').width()`.  It would always return zero.

I found a solution on here to get the width and height by creating a new image element and using the `onload` event to get those values.  I want to set the element's width and height to those values so that I can refer back to them.  No matter what I tried (attr, css, width), I get no results.  I cannot figure it out, so I am hoping someone here can help.

**HTML Source**

```
    <div id="image">
        <img id="photo">
    </div>

    <div id="debug"></div>
```

**JavaScript & jQuery Source**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
    function choosePhoto() {
    $('#photo').attr({
        src: "photo.gif",
        title: "Photo"
    });

    // determine width and height of new photo
    var img = document.getElementById('photo'),
        new_img = new Image();
    new_img.onload = function() {
        var imgWidth  = this.width,
            imgHeight = this.height;

        // one of my attempts at setting the width
        // value of an element outside this function.
        // 
        // How do I set the width and height values on the element
        // so that I can refer back to them again?
        $('#photo').attr({
            width: imgWidth
        });

        // this prints the correct dimensions
        $('#debug')
            .append("Original dimensions are : " + imgWidth + "x" + imgHeight + " pixels");
    }
    new_img.src = img.src;

    // this prints zero for the width
    $('#debug')
        .append("Image: " + $('#photo').width() + " x " + $('#photo').height() + "<br />");
}
...
});
```

Comment: `onload` will fire when image is loaded. Callback method

Comment: psst... https://code.google.com/p/jquery-imagefit-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the image source is asynchronous, therefore does not return immediately.

Try handling the load()

```
$("#photo").attr("src",new_src).load(function() {
  console.log($(this).width())
});
```

Comment: How do I set the CSS attribute, other attribute, or a variable based on your code?

Comment: Thank you! That does help; however, check out the updated code and note line 23 and the result it returns (i.e., the old width). I am looking at either using a function or attribute to get the new value, and I am so close!

Comment: Oddly, when I use the same code in my program, the numbers are all zero.  I don't understand why.

Comment: @user1138 paste the code to jsfiddle and we will see.

Comment: Let us all give a resounding, "Duh!"  The element containing the photo was hidden and it later is animated to display after this selection process. Is there a way to get those dimensions on an image that is actually hidden via an inherited style display:none?

Comment: I suppose I could use display:hidden instead, since the image will take up the same space.  But I would still like to find out if there is a way to read the width and height on an image that is set to display:none.

Comment: Not possible, you can try with visibility:hidden or show the image for a second, get the width and add display:none again. Here it's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903147/getting-width-of-div-with-a-parent-display-none-in-jquery-tab-control) topic on stackoverflow, you'll find it helpful. It explains what happens with image when has display:none; set.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  It's times like these I like to quote the original Sherlock Holmes: "You see, but you do not observe." ;)